# puppeteer: Can I tell if my site/app is browsed with pupeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm creating a small app that automates a few tasks.  I'd like to know if someone used the app (e.g. used puppeteer or some other way).

Is there some giveaway weather puppeteer is browsing or a user is browsing the site manually (different user agent or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the headers I currently receive from Puppeteer version v0.12.0:

```
{
  "host": "localhost:3001",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/64.0.3240.0 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}
```

In the user-agent `HeadlessChrome` is found, so a naive detection can be based on this.

Be aware that it is very easy for a crawler to change the user agent. Puppeteer exposes a `setUserAgent` method on its `page` instances. The docs can be [found here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetuseragentuseragent).

Comment: Thanks - so i could actually set the user agent and add `puppteer` and check based on that.

Comment: Yes, e.g. if you're using it for CI tests and want to filter it out of analytics, set the user agent to "puppeteer" (or whatever) and filter using that.